# Obter o Token de uma Api JWT

Tags: android, jwt, retrofit

Estou tendo problemas ao fazer a autenticação em uma api com padrão JWT, o token ele vem no header e usando o retrofit não estou conseguindo obtê-lo.
O consumo da api no Postman ocorre normalmente o recurso login, no corpo um json com as credenciais e-mail e senha, a requisição retorna um corpo vazio, já observando o header localizamos a informação do token.
Ao implementar o login no android sempre caio no onFailure ou seja eu não estou sabendo como obter/ler a informação que esta no cabeçalho.

Estou colocando o meu código abaixo primeiro a interface

```
  @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json"})
  @POST("login")
  Call<Authorization> login(@Body Credenciais cred);
```

agora onde estou consumindo, o que me chama atenção é que eu sei a api ela me retorna um corpo vazio e a informação que eu quero esta no header então quando eu tenho um Call para Authorization isto ao meu ver não estaria correto porque o retrofit ele vai querer fazer o parse do retorno para o objeto só que no corpo não volta nada e então.... pode ser que isto ai seja a causa do problema

```
    private void authenticate(String email, String password) {
    Log.i(TAG, "authenticate()" );

    Credenciais creds = new Credenciais(email, password);

    ApiUtil.getServiceClass().login(creds)
            .enqueue(new Callback<Authorization>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Authorization> call, Response<Authorization> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Token: " + response.headers().get("Authorization"));
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onResponse() - Não foi um sucesso");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Authorization> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onFailure() - Opá ocorreu uma falha " + t.getMessage());
                    call.cancel();
                }
            });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso do padrão JWT onde temos um retorno de corpo vazio o problema esta na assinatura da forma como esta abaixo esta errado o retrofit ele ira tentar serializar o objeto

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json"})
@POST("login")
Call<Authorization> login(@Body Credenciais cred);
```

Para corrigir vamos colocar void

```
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json"})
@POST("login")
Call<Void> login(@Body Credenciais cred);
```

e para obter o Token agora ficou assim

```
ApiUtil.getServiceClass().login(creds)
            .enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Token: " + response.headers().get("Authorization"));
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onResponse() - Não foi um sucesso");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onFailure() - Opá ocorreu uma falha " + t.getMessage());
                    call.cancel();
                }
            });
```

Espero que seja útil para quem estiver com o mesmo problema.